# How to do the derivative of log matrix with respect to scalar?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I am trying to find the good cost function for my optimization problem and I come across the logarithm of the matrix.

$$\log{(t\mathbf{Z})}$$

where $\log$ is a matrix logarithm and the matrix $t$ is a scalar input. We know that for exponential matrix, 
$$\frac{d e^{t\mathbf{A}}}{dt} = \mathbf{A}e^{t\mathbf{A}} = e^{t\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{A}$$

Can we do the same thing with logarithm, i.e.

$$\frac{d \log{(t\mathbf{Z})}}{dt} = (t\mathbf{Z})^{-1}$$

If not, then is there any other way to do the derivative?

Edit#1 : Correct the derivative result.

Comment: How are you defining $\log(tZ)$?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. $\mathbf{Z}$ is square matrix with only real value and $t$ is a scalar input. Does that answer your question?

Comment: What does it mean to take the logarithm of a matrix? Is it defined by a power series? A contour integral? In terms of the matrix exponential?

Comment: Logarithm of a matrix is defined by a power series, where $\log{(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A})} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\mathbf{A}^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

$$
\log(tZ) = \log(I + (tZ - I)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(tZ - I)^n
$$

then differentiating term by term, you get (formally)

$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\log(tZ) = Z\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(tZ - I)^{n-1} \\
 = Z\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}(tZ - I)^{n}\\
= Z(tZ)^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{t}I.
$$

You have to justify the steps, but this is the basic idea.

Alternatively, if you define the logarithm via the exponential, i.e.

$$
A(t) = \log(tZ) \Leftrightarrow \exp(A(t)) = tZ
$$

then you have

$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\exp(A(t)) = \dfrac{d}{dt}tZ \\
\exp(A(t))\dfrac{dA}{dt} = Z \\
tZ\dfrac{dA}{dt} = Z \\
\dfrac{dA}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{t}I. \\
$$

Note that $Z$ does not appear in the derivative (though we did use its invertibility). Compare to

$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} \log(\alpha x) = \dfrac{1}{x}
$$

for any $\alpha$ (either compute the derivative with the chain rule, or start with the identity $\log(\alpha x) = \log \alpha + \log x$)

Comment: If in place of $tZ$, we have $Z(t)$. Will the result be $\frac{dZ(t)}{dt}(Z(t))^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.